# Adding a Web Reference to Visual Studio WinForm Project

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, rest, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to get familiar with web services. I figured, I'd make some dinky little application using the Path of Exile resources. Found here: 
http://www.pathofexile.com/developer/docs/api-resources

Following these instructions on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

Doing Step 4 and tried to enter the URL listed on one of their pages, http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues, and when I hit "Go" it pops up with a download box asking me if I want to save the JSON file instead of just presenting a list of web services available for consumption. If I hit "Cancel" the browser goes back to the "home page" for Visual Studio and doesn't list any web services available.

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like their services is RESTful.

Comment: Those instructions are for adding SOAP based webservices, whereas the one you're wanting to use is JSON based

Comment: @RowlandShaw oh, I see. I thought it was the same steps. Been a few years since I had my Web Services class, don't remember what I'm doing.

Comment: How about, first writing your own XML Web service and then consuming it? Even more fun.

Comment: In fact, those instructions are for using the legacy ASMX service feature if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to play with some open to public SOAP web-services that can be consumed via Visual Studio Wizard take a look here [SOAP services](http://www.service-repository.com/)

Also if you have an access to sharepoint you can have some fun.
If you want to stick to PoE, then use NuGet and add JSON support.
cheers

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the SOAP stuff when I get home from work today. Seeing Rowland's comment on my original post I guess I didn't realize you added SOAP / REST differently.